# SMTP errors - PHPMailer based app

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I wrote an app based on PHPMailer that reads a CSV and retrieves the names and email addresses for the recipients (each recipient has a row) and sends emails to them and BCCs the emails to my work address (the same one as the one that sends the emails). It manages to send about 4-5 emails after which it starts returning errors, the most frequent being "SMTP connect() failed".

I use the SMTP server provided by Aruba Italy  - smtp.aruba.it, the one set up for our company email . Its limitations were confirmed to me by the representatives of the company and are max 250 emails sent every 20 minutes and no more than 3-4 simultaneous SMTP connections. Every time I used the app, I sent less than 100 emails in one batch and delayed every other email by one second to not have multiple SMTP connections opened at the same time.

I turned on debugging and read the errors returned but I do not really know how to interpret them. I pasted a few below.

Could anyone please help me determine what my problem is and how to repair it?

Than you.

```
2016-12-21 14:19:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2016-12-21 14:19:24 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 sender ok 
2016-12-21 14:19:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2016-12-21 14:19:24 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 recipient ok 
2016-12-21 14:19:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:
2016-12-21 14:19:24 SERVER -> CLIENT: 452 4.1.1 NeKD1u00T1ustzm01eKRZu policy violation 
2016-12-21 14:19:24 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 452 4.1.1 NeKD1u00T1ustzm01eKRZu policy violation 
2016-12-21 14:19:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2016-12-21 14:19:24 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2016-12-21 14:19:24 SMTP ERROR: DATA command failed: 
2016-12-21 14:19:24 SMTP Error: data not accepted. 
Message could not be sent.
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA command failed
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2016-12-21 14:36:30 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2016-12-21 14:36:30 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 sender ok 
2016-12-21 14:36:30 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2016-12-21 14:36:30 SERVER -> CLIENT: 452 4.1.1 Nec11u00u1ustzm01ecWgz policy violation 
2016-12-21 14:36:30 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 452 4.1.1 Nec11u00u1ustzm01ecWgz policy violation 2
016-12-21 14:36:30  CLIENT -> SERVER: RSET 
2016-12-21 14:36:30 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2016-12-21 14:36:30 SMTP ERROR: RSET command failed: 
2016-12-21 14:36:30 SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: [recipient's email address]: Nec11u00u1ustzm01ecWgz policy violation 
Message could not be sent.
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: [recipient's email address]: Nec11u00u1ustzm01ecWgz policy violation SMTP server error: RSET command failed
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2016-12-21 14:36:31 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 Connection: closed 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 Connection: opening to ssl://smtps.aruba.it:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 Connection: opened 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 421 smtpcmd05.ad.aruba.it bizsmtp NecX1u00y1ustzm01 policy violation 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 503 not available 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: 503 not available 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO localhost 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 503 not available 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 SMTP ERROR: HELO command failed: 503 not available 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 smtpcmd05.ad.aruba.it bizsmtp closing connection 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 Connection: closed 
2016-12-21 14:36:31 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting 
Message could not be sent.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2016-12-21 14:36:32 Connection: opening to ssl://smtps.aruba.it:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 Connection: opened 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 421 smtpcmd05.ad.aruba.it bizsmtp NecZ1u00g1ustzm01 policy violation 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 503 not available 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: 503 not available 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO localhost 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 503 not available 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 SMTP ERROR: HELO command failed: 503 not available 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 smtpcmd05.ad.aruba.it bizsmtp closing connection 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 Connection: closed 
2016-12-21 14:36:33 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting 
Message could not be sent.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2016-12-21 14:40:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2016-12-21 14:40:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2016-12-21 14:40:46 SMTP ERROR: MAIL FROM command failed: 
2016-12-21 14:40:46 The following From address failed: [sender's email address] : MAIL FROM command failed,,,SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed 
Message could not be sent.
Mailer Error: The following From address failed: [sender's email address]: MAIL FROM command failed,,,SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failedSMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed
```

Comment: In short, they're blocking you. `452 4.1.1 NeKD1u00T1ustzm01eKRZu policy violation` This means that you've hit some sort of policy block.

Comment: This is the same question you posted on GitHub, and the answer is the same here - contact your ISP.

Comment: I'll contact my ISP again to determine what went wrong. Thank you.

Comment: After all it was the ISP policy problem. I somewhat circumvented it by increasing the SMTP session listening time in XAMPP PHP and by adding a sleep time of 4-5 seconds after each mail. Further on I wrapped the whole thing in a loop construct (a finite one): It ended up taking a while but after several loops through the CSV it manages to send all the emails. It isn't any good for commercial use but it's perfect for what I need. It's not pretty but it works.